# struts2 iterating dropdown(s:select) inside <td> tag

Tags: struts2

I am iterating a list object in jsp file which is coming from action class. 
Using table,tr,td tags in order to dispay value in tabular format as follows.

```
<s:iterator value="userList" >
  <tr>
    <td><s:property value="name" /> </td>  
    <td><s:property value="gender" /> </td>     
    <td><s:select name="country" list="countryList" value="%{country}" /> </td>
    <td><s:property value="aboutYou"/> </td>  
    <td><s:property value="malingList /> </td>  
  <tr>
</s:iterator>
```

I need to display country drop down with selected value. **Which is displaying but not in a proper format**. Name and gender is showing in first line, country drop down showing in second line and aboutYou and mailing list showing in third line.

I tried to display drop down value inside  tag but not displaying.

**What i need to display is all five fields in one single line(tr)**

Requesting you please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the simple theme, or roll your own, or fit it within whatever theme you're using, which you don't mention.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working fine using theme="simple"  :)